# Remove campaign from mailing

Tags: civimail, civicampaign

this may seem like a silly question, but I copied a previous mailing and it copied the campaign from that mailing.  Now I can't figure out how to remove that campaign from my new mailing?

Comment: This won't help you now, but assuming you mean changing the campaign of a sent mailing, I've made changing campaign and name for a sent mailing possible in the UI recently, but it won't be available until 5.56:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24698

Comment: @LarsSG Thanks, but I meant removing a campaign completely from an unsent mailing.  It seems once you save a campaign you can't remove it.  The solution from pradeep nayak below worked for me!

Comment: Oh, you're right! That's silly, definitely broken. You should log an issue on Gitlab.

Comment: Are you using Mosaico and Shoreditch? Seems to be a specific problem with the workflow specific to those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the campaign for the mailing id **123** via one of the below method

1. Run SQL code

code:

```
UPDATE civicrm_mailing SET campaign_id = NULL WHERE id=123;
```

2. API 3 explorer - Navigate to CiviCRM >> Support >> Developer >> API Explorer v3

[image]

3. API 4 explorer - Navigate to CiviCRM >> Support >> Developer >> API Explorer v4
   [image]